# Subset first 500 rows by group, for a subset of groups

Tags: r, data.table, subset

This has got to be a simple answer.  I want to subset my data for testing purposes.  I have a data frame where I want to keep all columns of information, just simply reduce the number of observations PER individual.  So, I have a unique Identifier and about 50 individuals.  I want to select only 2 individuals AND and I want to select only 500 data points from those 2.

My data frame is called `wloc08`. There are 50 unique IDs. I am only taking 2 of those individuals but of those 2, I'd like only 500 data points from each.

```
subwloc08=subset(wloc08, subset = ID %in% c("F07001","F07005"))
```

somewhere in this statement can I use `[`?

```
 reduced= subwloc08$ID[1:500,]
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `lapply`:

```
do.call("rbind",
        lapply(c("F07001", "F07005"),
               function(x) wloc08[which(wloc08$ID == x)[1:500], ]))
```

Your command `reduced = subwloc08$ID[1:500,]` didn't work since `subwloc08$ID` is a vector. However, `reduced = subwloc08$ID[1:500]` would have worked but would have returned the first 500 values of `subwloc08$ID` (not the whole rows of `subwloc08`).

If you want to run this command for the first 30 subjects, you could use `unique(wloc08$ID)[1:30]` instead of `c("F07001", "F07005")`:

```
do.call("rbind",
        lapply(unique(wloc08$ID)[1:30],
               function(x) wloc08[which(wloc08$ID == x)[1:500], ]))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there any way to make this even more general?  So, lets say I didn't want to specify just 2 individuals, but 30 of them, and take a subset from each individual? Would I have to type all 30 names? or can I do something like lapply(wloc08[wloc08$ID[1:30]]), function(x).....

Comment: If you want to run this command for the first 30 subjects, you could use `unique(wloc08$ID)[1:30]` instead of `c("F07001", "F07005")`.

Comment: Cool! I deleted my previous comment to avoid future confusion.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein I tried the lapply(unique(wloc08$ID [1:30]), and it only returns the first 500 locations for the first individual.

Comment: Note that there is a `)` between `wloc08$ID` and `[1:30]` but not after the latter.

Answer (score 6):

If you're only dealing with 2 individuals, you could get away with subsetting each separately and then `rbind`ing each subset:

```
wloc08F07001 <- wloc08[which(wloc08$ID == "F07001")[1:500], ]

wloc08F07005 <- wloc08[which(wloc08$ID == "F07005")[1:500], ]

reduced <- rbind(wloc08F07001, wloc08F07005)
```

To make this more generalizable, especially if you are dealing with large amounts of data, you might consider looking at the `data.table` package. Here is an example

```
library(data.table)

wloc08DT<-as.data.table(wloc08)  # Create data.table

setkey(wloc08DT, "ID")           # Set a key to subset on

# EDIT: A comment from Matthew Dowle pointed out that by = "ID" isn't necessary
# reduced <- wloc08DT[c("F07001", "F07005"), .SD[1:500], by = "ID"]
reduced <- wloc08DT[c("F07001", "F07005"), .SD[1:500]]
```

To break down the syntax of the last step:

1. `c("F07001", "F07005")`: This will subset your data by finding all rows where the key is equal to `F07001` or `F07005`. It will also instigate "by without by" (see `?data.table` for details)
2. `.SD[1:500]`: This will subset the `.SD` object (the subsetted data.table) by selecting rows 1:500.
3. **EDIT** This part was removed thanks to a correction by Matthew Dowle. The "by without by" is initiated by step 1. Formerly: (`by = "ID"`: This tells `[.data.table` to perform the operation in step 2 for each ID individually, in this case only the IDs that you indicated in step 1.)

Comment: @Kerry, for a more generalizable solution, please see the edit above.

Comment: This is very interesting.  I will look more into data.tables.  Ive never come across them.  I often have situations where I need to do multiple commands across multiple individuals.

Comment: @BenBarnes Hi. All correct w.r.t. `.SD` etc, other than `by="ID"` isn't needed. `j` runs for each group in `i` anyway. That's important to take advantage of for efficiency. It's known as _by-without-by_, or, _grouping-by-i_. By including `by="ID"` it's making it work like a compound query: `wloc08DT[c("F07001", "F07005")][, .SD[1:500], by = "ID"]`, which is less efficient in this case where `i` joins to `ID` anyway.

Comment: Also, if there are a lot of groups, saving the `1:500` first in a variable such as `.head` may be worth it, to save creating the `1:500` vector over and over again for each group.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, thanks for the correction. In fact, I had built the syntax up from a compound query and forgot that the `by` isn't necessary.